# How to get the executable file name in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, console

When the compiler compiles code it spits out an executable.
What I want to do is grab the name of that executable when it runs. The only problem is every where I search, I only get ways to grab the whole path of the executable.

If I have an executable named `app.exe`, I want to output it in console.
People online say to use `GetModuleFileName`, `GetModuleBaseName`, and `argv[0]`, but all of those give me the full path to the .exe, like `C:\Users\Lone-PC\Desktop\app.exe`, and not just `app.exe` alone.

I don't want to use any libraries and this is all packed in a console application for a windows machine.

Comment: If you have the entire path, what stops you from parsing out the filename? You have strictly more information.

Comment: You have it in `argv[0]`, Parse it out. What issue do you have with that?

Comment: @HTNW What do you mean by parsing?

Comment: Process the string and figure out the filename from it. Breaking the string on the path separator and taking the last element would do it.

Comment: @HTNW I will be sure to try that, I'll let you know what happens.

Comment: @HTNW It works, I am posting the answer now.. Thanks :D

Comment: `GetModuleBaseName(GetCurrentProcess(), NULL, lpBaseName, nSize)` reliably does exactly what you want. It does not return the full path, just the base name.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found what I want thanks to user HTNW.
I have to process the directory, from the mentioned methods like `argv[0]`.

So I looked it up and borrowed code and made a function that will return the file name in a string.

Here is the code that solved my issue

```
string getFileName(string path) {
    string filename = path;
    const size_t last_slash_idx = filename.find_last_of("\\/");
    if (std::string::npos != last_slash_idx) {
        filename.erase(0, last_slash_idx + 1);
    }
    const size_t period_idx = filename.rfind('.');

    return filename;
}
```

Comment: Using `argv[0]` is unreliable if you need the real name of the executable. It's parsed from the command line, and a program can be started with an arbitrary command line when the `lpApplicationName` parameter of `CreateProcess` is used.